# I can't see the udp multicast traffic in my java application while I can see from the wireshark

Tags: java, networking, udp, nio, wireshark

I am trying to join udp multicast group to receive udp data in Windows 7 with jdk 1.8+ environment.

I am using NIO DatagramChannel to receive data. 
It seems my program works well cuz I can see udp traffic coming in through wireshark once I join the multicast group. ( I can not see any udp traffic while my program is not runnung. )

```
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(UDPGROUP_IP);
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(InetAddress.getByName(MY_IP));
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET) ;

channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true).bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
channel.join(group,ni);

channel.configureBlocking(false);

SocketAddress sa;
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

sa = channel.receive(buf);
if (sa != null ){

    byte[] byteReceived = new byte[BYTELEN]; 
    buf.flip();
    buf.get(byteReceived, 0, buf.limit());

    DefaultLogger.logger.info("Received :{}" , new String(byteReceived));

}
```

but when i try to receive data like above , it returns always null. 
I used to run this program with different env which have been worked well so far. I can not find any clue to figure this out.

I will appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: Your code snippet is not enough to understand where you have the problem. Try take a look on the following tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/multicastsocket-net/java-net-multicastsocket-example/

Comment: Is this the code you're running  ? you're using a non-blocking channel, you'll be very, very, very lucky if there happened to arrive a packet at the exact time you call `channel.receive(buf);`. Have you tried this with a blocking channel ?

Comment: Thank you for an advice, usually UDP channel that I am willing to listen is super flooding. So I used non-block mode .... but I also tried  `channel.configureBlock(true);` to figure out the problem, but unfortunately did not work, I would guess there might be something that I should check like rp_filter does in linux system... but don't know what it is...

Answer (score 0):

I was a fool that I did not even think about firewall.
3rd party security software that was installed in this PC was protecting my program to receive data packet.

thanks buddies.